# If $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow T$ is continuous and surjective, then $\varphi^{-1}(0,0)$ has infinitely many elements.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, contest-math

I'd like a **hint** for the following problem:

Let $T=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x=0\text{ or }y=0\}$. If $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow T$ is continuous with the Euclidean distance and surjective, then $\varphi^{-1}(0,0)$ is infinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $S=\varphi^{-1}\{(0,0)\}$ is finite.  Then $\varphi$ restricts to a continuous surjection $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus S\to T\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.  What can you say about each of these spaces?

Comment: Very slick!${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Eric Wofsey. When $X$ is a connected topological space and $A$ is a finite subset of $X$, is it always true that $X-A$ is connected?

Comment: Not always (consider $X=\mathbb{R}$, for instance).  So you have to do some work to prove it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the set $S = \varphi^{-1}(0,0)$ is finite, then the set $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus S$ is connected and the map $\varphi$ restricted to $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus S$ is continuous. Since continuous image of a connected set must be connected, the restriction map can not be continuous.(because the set $T \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$ is not connected)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, $\varphi ^{-1}(\{(0,0)\})$ is uncountable. If not, $\varphi ^{-1}(\{(0,0)\})$ is countable. It's well known that $\mathbb R^2 $ minus a countable set is connected (in fact, it's path connected). So then we have $\varphi $ mapping the connected set $\mathbb R^2\setminus \varphi ^{-1}(\{(0,0)\})$ onto the disconnected set $T\setminus \{(0,0)\},$ contradiction.